# $G$ is a group of order $7, f(x)=x^4, x \in G$. Is $f$ an isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

My first question: Is a group of order $7$ always Abelian? I think not, and I've proceeded with this assumption.

Since order of $G=7$, and order of every element must divide the order of the group, so order of any element in $G$ is either $1$ or $7$.

If $a,b \in G, O(a)=O(b)=1$, then $a=b=e, ab=e$. So $f(a)=e, f(b)=e, f(ab)=e$.

I'm stuck if the orders are $7$. Hence I can't prove if it's a homomorphism.

As for onto and one-one, since $G$ is a finite group, $f$ will be onto if and only if it is one-one. But I haven't been able to prove either. Please help!

Comment: Pick an element $a$ of order 7.  What is the subgroup generated by $a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group of prime order is cyclic, generated by any of its elements of order $>1$ (it's a consequence of Lagrange's theorem). Cyclic groups are trivially abelian.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the order of $G$ is $7$, then every non trivial element has order $7$, G=Z/7,
$f(x) =4x$ verifies $f(f(x))=x$.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Take $G$ the additive $\mathbb{F}_7$, then $f(f(1))=4 \cdot \overline{4}=\overline{2}$... I think it's $f \circ f \circ f=id$.